# Entity Framework tentando inserir registro duplicado

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Estou iniciando uma aplicação em Blazor, utilizando Entity Framework e banco MySQL.

Abaixo vou detalhar as Tabelas, Models, Contexto e Método que está me apresentando problema:

**Tabelas:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8UMW.png

**Contexto:**

```
public class ContextoEtapa : Contexto
{
    public DbSet<Etapa> Etapa { get; set; }
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class Etapa 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public bool Finalizadora { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("EtapaPai")]
    public virtual List<EtapaVinculada> ListaEtapaVinculada { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Table("etapa_vinculada")]
public class EtapaVinculada
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Column("id_etapa_pai")]
    public int EtapaPaiId { get; set; }

    public virtual Etapa EtapaPai { get; set; }

    [Column("id_etapa_filha")]
    public int EtapaFilhaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Etapa EtapaFilha { get; set; }
}
```

Código de exemplo que falha (**InnerException = {"Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'"}**):

```
public void Adicionar()
{
    try
    {
        var etapa = new Etapa();
        var etapaVinculada = new EtapaVinculada();

        etapa.ListaEtapaVinculada = new List<EtapaVinculada>();
        etapa.Descricao = "Aprovada";

        using (var contexto = new ContextoEtapa())
        {
            etapaVinculada.EtapaPai = etapa;
            etapaVinculada.EtapaFilha = contexto.Etapa.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault();
            etapaVinculada.Descricao = "Retornar para Desenvolvimento";

            etapa.ListaEtapaVinculada.Add(etapaVinculada);
        }

        using (var contexto = new ContextoEtapa())
        {
            contexto.Etapa.Add(etapa);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        throw excp;
    }
}
```

Obs: São códigos de exemplos que refletem uma situação real da minha aplicação. No meu caso eu preencho o objeto etapa em determinado momento utilizando um escopo de contexto, e depois para salvar no banco utilizo outro escopo de contexto, caindo então no erro de registro Duplicado (InnerException = {"Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'"}). Ao que me parece o Entity tenta inserir novamente na tabela de etapas o objeto da etapaVinculada de ID 2.

Obs2: Se eu fizer tudo dentro do mesmo escopo de contexto funciona corretamente.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz ae pra ver onde to errando, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de salvar, altera o valor da classe extrangeira para `null` (no seu caso é a propriedade `EtapaFilha`). Deixa valor apenas na propriedade que contem o valor da chave estrangeira (`EtapaFilhaId`).

Isso acontece porque o EF perdeu o trackeamento do objeto extrangeiro então ele acha que tem que criar esse objeto de novo no banco.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Olá, você já tentou utilizar DataAnnotations nos ids e UseIdentityColumns no Context?

[image: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity]

[image: UseIdentityColumns]

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Tentei no passado, mas por via das dúvidas tentei novamente e sem sucesso. Mesmo erro de duplicidade.